# Populate the DOM with JSON data

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom

Assuming that my angular app is provided data shaped as:

```
[
{
    name: 'object1',
    type: 'checkbox'
},
{
    name: 'object2',
    type: 'dropdown',
    options: ['opt1-1', 'opt1-2']
},
...
]
```

The aim is to populate the DOM with these objects. The type of elements I can have (such as checkbox, dropdowns) is predefined. Also, I will need these to interact together as they will be part of an interactive form. How can I store references to these on the `ts` side.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form Is that what you are asking? If not, can you clarify your question?

Comment: @DeborahK It might be confusing because I need two things: I need the form to be dynamic as the template (input fields) are given in the JSON input, and also I need the form to be reactive as the different input field need to communicate (in a unique direction/hierarchical) way.

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing that is built in to help you with this. The link I pointed you to should get your started.But it will be quite a project to have it dynamic (meaning no predefinition of anything) and yet make the code able to have knowledge of the relationships between the elements.